# Failure Modes for Synchronous Boost Low-Side MOSFET?

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

I'm looking for some input on possible failure-modes for the low-side MOSFET in a synchronous BOOST converter. I am using LM5122: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5122.pdf

Out of 50 units built, 2 units failed in a similar way, taking out the same 5 or 6 components. My most plausible explanation is that the low-side MOSFET failed first, and the subsequent parts failed as a results. Other parts were the controller IC, and a few parts in the IC's external VCC supply circuit. I think the MOSFET failed drain-to-gate and the rest is history.

So far the following testing has been done:

1. Check IC's VCC voltage is within acceptable range for all input voltage, and output load conditions --*-- Constant 13V across all conditions*
2. Check for excessive drain-source voltage at low-side MOSFET shut-off *--- Never observed higher than 50V at the peak, many line/load conditions, 60V rated*
3. Check for excessive gate-source voltage during switching *--- Essentially matches VCC voltage @ 13V, 20V rated*
4. Check for excessive dv/dt across drain-source during switching *--- 1 to 3V/ns maximum, many line/load conditions, manufacturer states ~10V/ns minimum*

Although the details are a little shaky, supposedly the 2 units that failed (during ATE testing), failed while (or shortly after) transitioning the input voltage from 0 - 15V (unit #1) and from 15V - 36V (unit # 2). I've heard of things like low-side MOSFET reverse current failure in synchronous buck converters, but I am not sure if similar scenario is possible in syn. boost. In summary, it seems related to the input voltage transitioning, or some other transitory state, as the steady state operation looks fine, from what I can tell.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: How is the input voltage transition done during the test? Relay switching between two power supplies? Or is it "soft"? If it is hard switching, suspect input ferrite bead causing resonance with input or supply cap and huge voltage peak on input. Might be worth checking what happens on the input when the test setup switches voltage.

Comment: The input voltage switching is done via Agilent 6030A programmable DC source. So, not hard switching...should be controlled rise-time (although I am not 100% sure the exact slew rate). The input is also protected by a TVS with ~40-58V clamping voltage, depending on current through it. It *seems* like there shouldn't be a spike on the input voltage. Could be wrong! Thanks.

Comment: At startup, a boost has a path from Vin to Vout through the inductor and the body diode of the sync FET.  That can cause a large uncontrolled inrush current.  IF that inrush current saturates the inductor and if the low side FET starts to switch while the inductor is saturated it can easily kill the FET.  Not sure if that's happening, but you might want to check.   If it is, you can put a diode across the inductor to carry the inrush current and prevent saturation.

Comment: Thank you! I know this is typical in boost PFC to protect the main diode (particularly if a delicate SiC type) from high surge current. I never considered the idea of the boost inductor saturating and presenting an unimpeded VIN to the low-side MOSFET drain. LM5122 has a built in start-up delay that should wait some time after output caps are charged to VIN before starting switching. Will double check the delay. Seems any saturation situation could lead to low-side failure. But, this explanation does not really make too much sense for the unit #2 case which failed after 15-36V VIN transition.

Comment: @TimNJ Agreed on unit#2, and the start-up delay, so unless something strange is going on, inrush saturation probably isn't the issue.  Just thought I'd throw it out there as something to check though.

Comment: @JohnD Yes, I appreciate the input. Helped me to open my mind to some other ideas.